# Java Reflection to Instantiate Generics at Runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection, minecraft

I'm trying to integrate my application with [Bukkit - A Minecraft Server API](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit).

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how could I get functionality like this to work:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mycompany");    
Set<Class<? extends BlockEvent>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(BlockEvent.class);
for (Class<? extends BlockEvent> clazz : classes) {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new BlockListener<clazz>(), this);
}
```

I want to register a listener for all event types that extend [BlockEvent](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockEvent.java). Events are registered by passing an implemention of [Listener](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/event/Listener.java) into the [registerEvents(Listener, Plugin)](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/PluginManager.java#L113) method exposed by the Bukkit API's [PluginManager](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Bukkit.java#L223). Obviously `clazz` is not a type and cannot be used as such.

Here is the generic class:

```
public class BlockListener<T extends BlockEvent> implements Listener {
  @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST, ignoreCancelled = true)
  void onBlock(T event) {
    System.out.println("Block Event");
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(new BlockChangeEvent(event.getBlock()));
  }
}
```

**Update**

```
    public Map<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>> createRegisteredListeners(@NotNull Listener listener, @NotNull final Plugin plugin) {
        Validate.notNull(plugin, "Plugin can not be null");
        Validate.notNull(listener, "Listener can not be null");

        boolean useTimings = server.getPluginManager().useTimings();
        Map<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>> ret = new HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>>();
        Set<Method> methods;
        try {
            Method[] publicMethods = listener.getClass().getMethods();
            Method[] privateMethods = listener.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            methods = new HashSet<Method>(publicMethods.length + privateMethods.length, 1.0f);
            for (Method method : publicMethods) {
                methods.add(method);
            }
            for (Method method : privateMethods) {
                methods.add(method);
            }
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            plugin.getLogger().severe("Plugin " + plugin.getDescription().getFullName() + " has failed to register events for " + listener.getClass() + " because " + e.getMessage() + " does not exist.");
            return ret;
        }

        for (final Method method : methods) {
            final EventHandler eh = method.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class);
            if (eh == null) continue;
            // Do not register bridge or synthetic methods to avoid event duplication
            // Fixes SPIGOT-893
            if (method.isBridge() || method.isSynthetic()) {
                continue;
            }
            final Class<?> checkClass;
            if (method.getParameterTypes().length != 1 || !Event.class.isAssignableFrom(checkClass = method.getParameterTypes()[0])) {
                plugin.getLogger().severe(plugin.getDescription().getFullName() + " attempted to register an invalid EventHandler method signature \"" + method.toGenericString() + "\" in " + listener.getClass());
                continue;
            }
            final Class<? extends Event> eventClass = checkClass.asSubclass(Event.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Set<RegisteredListener> eventSet = ret.get(eventClass);
            if (eventSet == null) {
                eventSet = new HashSet<RegisteredListener>();
                ret.put(eventClass, eventSet);
            }

            for (Class<?> clazz = eventClass; Event.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz); clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) {
                // This loop checks for extending deprecated events
                if (clazz.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) != null) {
                    Warning warning = clazz.getAnnotation(Warning.class);
                    WarningState warningState = server.getWarningState();
                    if (!warningState.printFor(warning)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    plugin.getLogger().log(
                            Level.WARNING,
                            String.format(
                                    "\"%s\" has registered a listener for %s on method \"%s\", but the event is Deprecated. \"%s\"; please notify the authors %s.",
                                    plugin.getDescription().getFullName(),
                                    clazz.getName(),
                                    method.toGenericString(),
                                    (warning != null && warning.reason().length() != 0) ? warning.reason() : "Server performance will be affected",
                                    Arrays.toString(plugin.getDescription().getAuthors().toArray())),
                            warningState == WarningState.ON ? new AuthorNagException(null) : null);
                    break;
                }
            }

            final CustomTimingsHandler timings = new CustomTimingsHandler("Plugin: " + plugin.getDescription().getFullName() + " Event: " + listener.getClass().getName() + "::" + method.getName() + "(" + eventClass.getSimpleName() + ")", pluginParentTimer); // Spigot
            EventExecutor executor = new EventExecutor() {
                @Override
                public void execute(@NotNull Listener listener, @NotNull Event event) throws EventException {
                    try {
                        if (!eventClass.isAssignableFrom(event.getClass())) {
                            return;
                        }
                        // Spigot start
                        boolean isAsync = event.isAsynchronous();
                        if (!isAsync) timings.startTiming();
                        method.invoke(listener, event);
                        if (!isAsync) timings.stopTiming();
                        // Spigot end
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        throw new EventException(ex.getCause());
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        throw new EventException(t);
                    }
                }
            };
            if (false) { // Spigot - RL handles useTimings check now
                eventSet.add(new TimedRegisteredListener(listener, executor, eh.priority(), plugin, eh.ignoreCancelled()));
            } else {
                eventSet.add(new RegisteredListener(listener, executor, eh.priority(), plugin, eh.ignoreCancelled()));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Specifically

```
method.getParameterTypes()[0]
```

Does not work with generics.

Comment: Please put here the signature of `registerEvents` method.

Comment: what registerEvents does is look for method(s) in the class that have a parameter that extends `Event`. The second argument is just a reference to the Plugin instance.

Comment: Jugbot. The Bukkit API links & minecraft tag that [*I edited your post with*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26963481) are the kinds of things that you should've included in your question to begin with. Having that kind of information available *before-hand*, saves people who might consider investigating a solution to your question, from wasting their time. That same information that I added — *had you researched it and found it yourself* — might also have lead *you* to discover days earlier than you did that „*`method.getParameterTypes()[0] Does not work with generics`*“.

Comment: Deduper. The accepted answer answered my original question just fine. I just so happened to encounter a different issue when trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic method which returns you the BlockEventListenerObject, something like this:

```
private static <T extends BlockEvent> BlockEventListener<T> getBlockEventListener(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new BlockEventListener<T>();
}
```

Then you can call it from your loop,

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(getBlockEventListener(clazz), this);
```

Comment: The second T should be BlockEventListener.

Comment: @Jugbot Yeah, my bad.. Edited!

Comment: Hmm for some reason the BlockEventListener that returns is always being interpreted as  `BlockEventListener<BlockEvent>`

Comment: Did you realize you're never using the _`clazz`_ formal parameter at all in the body of the method: _`getBlockEventListener(Class<T> clazz){ ... }`_. Is that intentional? If yes, then can you explain your choice please? TIA.

Comment: ...also, please can you answer the same question that @Jugbot asked me: „*What's the code for block listener?*“ — I presume OP means the generic class declaration (_`class BlockListener<T extends BlockEvent>...`_ ); including the implementation of _`onBlock()`_. Have I understood your question correctly, Jugbot?

Comment: On inspection of the source code I found that the Listener is registered by finding the class of the argument used through `method.getParameterTypes()[0]`... which unfortunately doesn't work well with generics.

Answer (score 0):

> „*…Basically how could I get functionality like this to work…*“

[*Here is one way*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307921)…

```
...
public void use( final Set< Class < ? extends BlockEvent > > classes, PluginManager pluginMgr ) throws ReflectiveOperationException { 
    
    for( Class < ? extends BlockEvent > clazz : ( classes ) ){ 
        
        pluginMgr.registerEvents( new BlockListener< >( clazz.newInstance( ) ), this );
    }        
}
...
```

I've implemented some *stand-in* classes to make the experiment testable. I used the experimental classes like this…

```
...    
final Set< Class < ? extends BlockEvent > > classes = new HashSet< >( );
    
classes.add( BlockParty.class );

final PluginManager pluginMgr = new PluginManager( );
    
final Deduper experimental = new DeduperAnswer( );
    
experimental.use( classes, pluginMgr );
...
```

Click the green ***Start*** button [*at the top of the page*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_307921) and observe this output…

```
BlockChangeEvent [ block: Block@404b9385 ]
                          Havana Block Party!
                     EXPERIMENT SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: „*...What's the code for block listener?...*“ — Are you unable to [*access the experiment*](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_307921) I shared 2 links to in the answer? On the right hand side of the *IDE* at that location, expand the „*source*“ node (*if it isn't automatically expanded for you*). Is there not a _`BlockListener.java`_ file there? Is that the „*code*“ you're asking about? Please let me know if you mean something else? TIA. You can run the experiment at that location by clicking the green ***Start*** button at the top of [*the page*](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_307921). HTH.

Comment: I took a look but you changed the functionality of the BlockListener. Only the method with generic param T is necessary. I'll try to add more information about how this listener is consumed by the api I am using.

Comment: „*...you changed the functionality of the BlockListener. Only the method with generic param T is necessary*...“ — The changes are ***necessary*** „*to make it testable*“; like I said in my answer, @Jugbot. Tests are ***needed*** to resolve your error. You said your use case is: „*to register a listener for all event types that extend BlockEvent*“. Help me understand how the *test* methods I added makes it impossible to „*register a listener for all event types*“? Or maybe it will be easier for you to explain how the methods I added, fail to solve the compilation error you originally reported?

Comment: „*...Only the method with generic param T is necessary*...“ — You do realize that you are ***not*** required to add the *test* methods I introduced in my ***stand-in*** _`BlockListener`_, to your IRL _`BlockListener`_? Right, @Jugbot? Just so it's clear: *The methods I've introduced in the **stand-in** have **zero** affect on the correctness of the **actual** solution I've proposed to solve your problem*. ***DO NOT*** add _`getBlockEvents()`_  to your IRL _`BlockListener`_. It is there for testing ***ONLY***. Let me know if you need me to explain that in more detail? TIA.